# Troubles installing/starting Redis via Resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

Trying to complete instructions for Resque/Redis installation here:

```
https://github.com/defunkt/resque/blob/master/README.markdown
```

Am stuck at where I'm trying to start up Redis via Resque at the following command:

```
Craig:/usr/local/src/resque$ rake redis:start
(in /usr/local/src/resque)
Detach with Ctrl+\  Re-attach with rake redis:attach
../../bin/dtach -A /tmp/redis.dtach ../../bin/redis-server ../../../etc/redis.conf
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (127): [../../bin/dtach -A /tmp/redis.dtach ../../...]

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Rerunning with --trace (showing only part of trace):

```
Craig:/usr/local/src/resque$ rake redis:start --trace
(in /usr/local/src/resque)
** Invoke redis:start (first_time)
** Execute redis:start
Detach with Ctrl+\  Re-attach with rake redis:attach
../../bin/dtach -A /tmp/redis.dtach ../../bin/redis-server ../../../etc/redis.conf
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (127): [../../bin/dtach -A /tmp/redis.dtach ../../...]
/Users/craigflannagan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@foo/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:995:in `block in sh'
```

Not sure what is wrong here - by the way, when I did those instructions

```
$ git clone git://github.com/defunkt/resque.git
$ cd resque
$ PREFIX=<your_prefix> rake redis:install dtach:install
$ rake redis:start
```

I wasn't sure whether or not I was supposed to be doing #1 from within the Rails project, or if I was supposed to have the git clone create a new folder outside the Rails project (in this case, I chose to have folder created outside the project).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install Redis and dtach using a custom prefix, you also need to pass that prefix when starting Redis. Otherwise, the Resque Rakefile will try to look for `redis-server` in `/usr/local` (or so I believe).

Alternatively, you can just download, install and run Redis yourself (see: [this page](http://redis.io/download)).

Comment: That was indeed it, thanks! 

All I simply had to do was:
    PREFIX=myprefix rake redis:start